# Wpf binding when property of the viewmodel is changed

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding

My wpf project follows the MVVM pattern. In my view-model I have an IList of obejcts which I take from database. Every object from this IList has a property which is List.

When I open the view for that view-model, I have an ItemsControl with this property:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding TheIListOfObjects}"
```

and the items in that ItemsControl are actually showing information from List.

So, while the user is on the view, an itemscontrol is shown. What I want to do is this: while on the same view, if the user clicks a button, the List is changed. How can I make the ItemsControl to refresh and show the new info?

Comment: looks like this can be done automatically with `INotifyCollectionChanged`, your list source should be an `ICollectionView` or an `ObservableCollection`.

Comment: What you need is, you have a List of SomeClass. Then, when a button is pressed, the information changes in List, and in the view is possible see it.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to have is ObservableCollection type for the property type.

## Xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Click" Click="Button_Click" />
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding People}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

## Xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Person> _people = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
    public ObservableCollection<Person> People
    {
        get { return _people; }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        People.Add(new Person { Name = "A" });
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your Button_Click method break MVVM Pattern

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that changes in a collection are notified to its bound controls, you must use `ObservableCollection<>` instead of `IList<>`

Answer (score 0):

In WPF, once we have data bound a collection to the `ItemsSource` property of a collection control, we *don't* refresh the `ItemsSource` property, or interact with it in any other way. Instead, we work with the data bound property value, so for your example...:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding TheIListOfObjects}"
```

... you should manipulate the `TheIListOfObjects` collection:

```
TheIListOfObjects = GetNewCollectionItems();
```

If you have correctly implemented the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in your view model, then your view should update as expected.